# Detect press at camera record button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, camera

I need to know when the record button at the camera gets pressed so that I can implement a few things at the press.
Does anybody know how to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With default UIPicker,I think its not possible.

You don't get notified when the user taps the button but you can provide your own capture button

Hide its standard image picker controls (showsCameraControls) and provide a custom overlay view (cameraOverlayView). In that overlay view, place a custom button that you connect to a target/action.

Comment: I'm in quite a bit of a hurry, so I'll put this project on hold. However it seems to be right, so you'll get the check. Thanks!